# copy paste from/to GUI Emacs not working -- Windows 7

Tags: microsoft-windows, copy-paste, clipboard

I have an issue with `copy` and `paste` from or to Emacs (GUI); as precised in the title, I'm using Windows 7. The Emacs version is 25.1.1

`kill` and `yank` are working properly though ; to `copy` or `paste`, I have to use the mouse, which is annoying.

I have nothing special in my .emacs file, I added the following lines but nothing has changed :

```
(setq select-enable-primary t)
(setq select-enable-clipboard t)
(setq save-interprogram-paste-before-kill t)
```

thanks in advance for your insights.

Comment: It's not clear to me what behavior you are seeing. When you copy from another Windows application and then switch to Emacs and `yank`, it does not work? But there is something you can do with the mouse that /does/ work? You should try running emacs with `-Q` and see if the problem persists, otherwise it is likely an issue in your .emacs file. Note that I have the Emacs 25.1.1 defaults for all the variables you mention and Windows clipboard works as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

I use simpleclip, there is a short explanation on the github page for what may be going on:

https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip

I bind simpleclip-paste to f9 f9

Comment: thanks, I've tried but it does not do the trick...

Comment: What didn't work?  simpleclip works for me on Windows 7. Note I have to use Ctrl-Insert as the key-press to copy, since Super-C is intercepted by the OS. This is using the default key bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is really caused by Windows OS. I am using Win7 and simple.el to support the basic copy, cut and paste operations, which work quite well. And my recommendations are:

- **key binding**: try "C-h k", and press the key you bind to paste or copy operations (by default, it is "C-y"), to test whether your key binding is correct.
- **package error**: turn the debug with "toggle-debug-on-error", and run the copy functions. By looking at the backtrace, you will probably find errors out. *Based on your describing, it is less likely to be a function error.*